# How to get values of a dualKnob ionRange component in ionic/react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to get the values of my dualKnob IonRange component in React, but I just can't get the lower and upper values. Has someone experienced similar problems before and knows how to fix the issue?

Here's my code:

```
const SearchOptions = () => {
  let lower = 0;
  let upper = 3000;

  return (
    <IonList>
      <IonListHeader>Search Options</IonListHeader>
      <IonItem>
        <IonRange
          min={0}
          max={3000}
          dualKnobs={true}
          pin={true}
          onIonChange={e => {
            lower = e.target.value.lower;
            upper = e.target.value.upper;
          }}
        >
          <IonLabel slot='start'>{lower}</IonLabel>
          <IonLabel slot='end'>{upper}</IonLabel>
        </IonRange>
      </IonItem>
    </IonList>
  );
};

export default SearchOptions;
```

Can someone please help me as I'm stuck very hard banging my head against my table right now :(
Thank you beforehand!

Comment: How do you mean by "get the lower and upper values"? What behaviour do you expect aside from what this sandbox provides: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-lederberg-4ggdn?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I want to get the lower and upper values from the dualKnobs, so the position they are currently at, for example if the right knob is a t 1500, I want the upper value to be set to 1500 aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the upper and lower values were being set but the the IonLabel's were not reflecting/re-rendering to show this change.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this with classless components but I don't know it so I will just give you the code for a way which works using a class component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    IonList,
    IonListHeader,
    IonItem,
    IonRange,
    IonLabel
} from "@ionic/react";

type sliderProps = {}

type sliderState = {
    lower: any,
    upper: any
}

class Slider extends React.Component<sliderProps, sliderState> {
    constructor(props: sliderProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            lower: 0,
            upper: 3000
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event: any) =>{
        this.setState({
            lower: event.target.value.lower,
            upper: event.target.value.upper
        })
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <IonList>
                <IonListHeader>Search Options</IonListHeader>
                <IonItem>
                    <IonRange
                        min={0}
                        max={3000}
                        dualKnobs={true}
                        pin={true}
                        onIonChange={(e)=> this.handleChange(e)}
                    >
                        <IonLabel slot="start">{this.state.lower}</IonLabel>
                        <IonLabel slot="end">{this.state.upper}</IonLabel>
                    </IonRange>
                </IonItem>
            </IonList>
        )
    }

}

export default Slider;
```

This works because calling `this.setState` causes re-render of the component.

Like I said, i'm sure there are nicer ways to do this but this one works! Make sure to import it to the component you want to use it on, and include it in the return function:

```
import Slider from '../components/slider';
...

return(
    <div>Below is an updating slider</div>
    <Slider />
)
```

**Edit:**

Or if you would prefer not to use a class method:

```
onIonChange={(event: any) => {
                            this.setState({
                                lower: event.target.value.lower,
                                upper: event.target.value.upper
                            })
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Works fine now, thanks alot :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help.